# RGeo: spatial data in fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rgeo

I've got a model containing a location attribute, represented by a RGeo::Cartesian::Point object, and stored in my database as spatial data.

In order to run tests, I need to create some samples of such a model through fixtures.

I tried several different syntaxes to initialize the location attribute in erb YAML, but none of them worked.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same challenge and I used FactoryGirl to define the spatial data:

```
factory :obj, class :class do
  geo "POINT(48.32414 2.12665)"
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

We're using a slightly different type of object, but with the RGeo library I was able to create an RGeo point in a Rails test fixture .yml file like this:

```
bbq_restaurant:
  location: <%= RGeo::Cartesian.factory(:srid => 4326).parse_wkt("POINT(-94.621023 39.044396)") %>
```